# Gaussian fit: find the X values for a given Y

Tags: python, gaussian

I did the best fit for my Gaussian curve with Python. Once I have the best fit curve, I would like to know for a given Y value, the correspondent X values.

Since it is a Gaussian curve, I should have two values of X for a given Y ( less than the max value of Y).

How could I do it on Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's take for instance your Gaussian : g(x) = a * exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2)) with a, x0 and sigma being your found parameters from the fit.

```
And now you want to find y such as y = g(x)  
<=> y = a * exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))  
<=> ln|y/a| = -(x - x0) ** 2  / (2 * sigma ** 2))  
<=> - ln|y/a| * (2 * sigma ** 2)) =(x - x0) ** 2  
<=> sqrt(- ln|y/a| * (2 * sigma ** 2))) = +/- (x - x0)  
<=> x = +/- (x0 + sqrt(- ln|y/a| * (2 * sigma ** 2))))
```

Then, you can use:

```
def inv_gaus(y, a, x0, sigma):
    x = x0 + np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(y / a) * sigma ** 2)
    return -x, x
```

And therefore you have 2 x for one y :)

Comment: It probably should be `return x0 -x, x0 + x` since both solutions may have the same sign.
Also, `a` can be safely replaced with `1/(sigma*(2*np.pi)**0.5)`